# How to pass state from one redux duck to another?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using [pepperoni-app-kit](https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit), which uses react-native, react-redux, redux-loop, and various other things.

I have one [Redux Duck](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) that's in charge of authentication.  When login is complete, it writes some important session information to the `['auth', 'env']` section of the store.

I have another duck called Browse that's in charge of browsing a list of data.  That duck needs access to the `env` data in order to make a server request.

The state tree looks like this:

```
state
  +-- auth
        +-- env
  +-- browse
        +-- ...
```

I can figure out how to pass `['auth','env']` to my BrowseView no problem by using my BrowseViewContainer to `connect()` the `['auth','env']` data to the view.  eg:

```
   connect(
      state => ({
        env: state.getIn(['auth', 'env']),
        ...
      })
    )(BrowseView)
```

However, I don't need the `env` in my BrowseView, I need it in my Browse duck, because the duck is the one making the http request that needs the `env`.

What's the best way for me to pass state information (`env`) from one part of the state tree (`auth`) to another (`browse`)?  Or alternately, is there a better place for me to store this information than in `auth` so that it's more easily accessible from other ducks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that redux-thunk is one way to do this, and pepperoni-app-kit is already using redux-thunk.

Instead of returning an action from my action creator I return a thunk object, and the thunk has access to the complete state tree.

For example, my original action creator looked like:

```
export function list () {
  const env = ??? // where to get env?
  return {
    type: LIST_RESPONSE,
    payload: getList(env)
  }
}
```

And the rewritten one using thunk:

```
export function list () {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const env = getState().get('auth').get('env')
    dispatch({
      type: LIST_RESPONSE,
      payload: getList(env)
    })
  }
}
```